# Error correction codes - with strong noise

Tags: error-correcting-codes

I was reading [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/how-was-magnetic-tape-decay-prevented-in-voyager-1) answer on how error-correction works on magnetic tape recorders for the Voyager space probes.
After watching one or two youtube videos I understand the principle of Hamming-coding and that some sort of this is probably used in encoding the Voyager data.

Also it is known that simple Hamming-encoding can't handle large numbers of errors, particularly when nasty combinations of wrong data and parity appear.

Now if we transmit a Hamming-code, which is essentially 50% error-correction bits, through the solar system in the presence of strong noise sources, this becomes relevant.

Maybe we could think of adding more layers of parity bits that check parity bits, or 'outer codes' to correct those. But then, the stronger the noise source gets, the more encoding we need and so the percentage of actual data transmitted decreases more and more.

I'm by far not an expert in this field, so here's my question:

- What kind of smart encoding can we use, when we expect a high percentage of all transmitted bits (including a large percentage of parity bits, which could make a large percentage of the total message) to be corrupted? I guess I'd be satisfied with just the keywords or a good youtube video, then I can google the rest, but ofc a short answer outlining the ideas would be nice!

Comment: There's an entire area devoted to constructing error-correcting codes, known as *coding theory*. You can find many lecture notes online.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Well, i'm interested in this specific problem, not in the whole area. It's interesting for me, but not interesting enough to invest my whole week into that. That's why i came here.

Comment: This problem is in fact the mainstay of coding theory. You're interested in the high-noise regime, whereas coding theory is interested in all noise regimes, but many of the principles will be the same regardless of the exact error rate. Unfortunately coding theory is quite a large area, so it's really difficult to outline the ideas in a short answer, though perhaps someone will try.